# Unable to migrate Django models

Tags: python, django

So I'm trying to automatically assign the current logged in user to a variable in my model. I think this make sense but I'm not able to migrate the models and it is going me this error.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import date

# Create your models here.
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    portfolio_site = models.URLField(blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank='True')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class UserPosts(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    post_sub_title = models.CharField(max_length=250,unique=False)
    post_author = models.ForeignKey('User',User.username)
    post_date = models.DateField(default=date.today,blank=True)
    post_body = models.TextField(max_length=1000,unique=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.post_title)
```

The Error:

```
ValueError: Cannot create form field for 'post_author' yet, because its related model 'User' has not been loaded yet
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @BradRhoads I think so, or it's no longer relevant. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just deleted the migrations and then migrated again from scratch...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotation from this line:

```
post_author = models.ForeignKey('User',User.username)
```

It should be like this:

```
post_author = models.ForeignKey(User,User.username)
```

Comment: I just updated that and now it says this: ERRORS:
blog.UserPosts.post_author: (fields.E312) The to_field '<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x10fb35a20>' doesn't exist on the related model 'auth.User'.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
post_author = models.ForeignKey('User',User.username)
```

Your ForeignKey want's to use the attribute 'username' of the imported User. Not of your User object when related.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this I don't really understand what you mean that last part "not of your User object when related"

Comment: _post_author = models.ForeignKey('User',User.username)_ --> A ForeignKey to a quoated Model (here: 'Users') is used, when you need to "delay" the actual import of that Model. You did that well. But with your second arg in ForeignKey your want to access the User.username where User is not your related Model 'User' but your **not** delayed imported User. So if you remove the second arg from your ForeignKey the problem could be resolved.

Comment: I think I did what your saying correctly but it gave me a completely new error. I removed it to: post_author = models.ForeignKey('User') and the new error it gave was -> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Author'

Comment: try `auth.User` to ensure `User` will be the model of app `auth`

Comment: Like this: `post_author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',User.username)`? It still gives my an error.

Comment: Does the error occure if you remove User.username? `post_author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')`

Comment: It gives new error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Select Author'
`